# WordPress's wpcli is using http and not https for plugin updates

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I have a WordPress instance which when I attempt to update a plugin via the wpcli like so:

```
wp plugin update akismet
```

returns the following:

```
Downloading update from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.4.1.11.zip...
Warning: Download failed. "cURL error 77: "
+---------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| name    | old_version | new_version | status |
+---------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| akismet | 4.1.10      | 4.1.11      | Error  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+--------+
Error: No plugins updated.
```

I observed that the issue might be linked to the fact that the download uses 'http' and not 'https'. I have not been to figure out what the cause might be and how to fix it. How may I 'force' wpcli to use https, or some other approach to this please? Thanks